# How to get element by class name in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

So in vanilla **JavaScript** you can just `const menuConst = document.getElementsByTagName("menu")` and use `menuConst` to manipulate with it.
Idea is when u click on button menu will be changing styles from display none to flex and height gonna change from 0 to 22rem, usually in JS i was using SetTimeout function to change the height value with transition
But in Vue.js i have no idea how to that because can't get element by class.

```
<button class="menu__button"
        :class="{active:activeToggle}"
        @click= "activeToggle = !activeToggle; menuToggle();">
</button>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default{
    name: "Button",
    data(){
        return{
            activeToggle:false
        }
    },
    methods:{
        menuToggle(){
            if( this.activeToggle == true){
                // get .menu and change styles
            }
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`template refs`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) to do this:

```
<div class="menu" ref="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

export default {
  name: 'Button',
  data() {
    return {
      activeToggle: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    menuToggle() {
        if (this.activeToggle == true) {
          // Access the menu using template $refs
          const menu = this.$refs.menu
        }
    },
  },
}
```